# Problems with decimals in PowerBI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, business-intelligence

I'm preparing some reports using PBI and while I was checking all data is correct, I've ran into some disparities between the database (SQL Server) and PBI data.

In my report I am  calculating the sum of one column (price). In SQL Server the type of data is decimal(18,4). When i calculate the sum in SQL the results are different (like 0.4, nothing big) but i don't understand the data are not the same. In PBI the data type of that column is also a decimal with 4 digits after the point.

Messing a bit around with the total digits in PBI I've found some of the values are messed up. For example, a value could have 0.00000001 more or less than it is in the database. I'm not sure, but this could be my problem (the database has around 4 million rows, so this could lead to the 0.4 difference).

Am i doing something wrong? Is this a known error?

If you need more info just ask. Thank you all. I hope I've explain my problem clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is a [data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-data-types) issue where Power BI is using floats versus the SQL decimal(18,4).

Try using the Fixed Decimal Number data type instead of the default Decimal Number.

Comment: ok, doing that the difference has decreasedbut still not the same. Could it work if i was using float instead of decimal (18,4) in the database?

Comment: Not sure. How are you having differences of 0.00000001 with only 4 decimal places of precision though?

Comment: i don't know. This is my totally new to me. But for sure in the database only shows 4 decimals, even if i convert it.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this issue even if I converted it into DECIMAL(19,2) and MONEY.
My guess is since SSMS is still in 32-bit while PowerBI is 64-bit.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).